# Rails3 - routing: How do you create a root path for a database-driven item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

## Background info

- I have an app where users can make microsites ala http://myname.the_app.com.
- Microsite has_many :pages
- Each Microsite belongs_to :landing_page (which is a Page) that determines where the visitor is fowarded when they view the site. Right now the app does a `redirect_to @microsite.landing_page`. The visitor then sees a url like so: `http://myname.the_app.com/pages/id

**How can I render the landing page but keep the root path?** I want to be able to see the "about page" but with the url `http://myname.the_app.com`.

## An option

Here's an option: have a home_controller#index action that instantiates all the `page` variables it needs. *However*... I'm holding this off because what if I have more than page? What if I want the landing_page to be something else in the future, like a `contact_form` located at `/contact_forms/id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps render :template => "pages/#{whatever_id}" might solve your problem. Just replace your redirect_to with the render...

Comment: This would be in the home_controller right? Similar to my option?

Comment: Thanks Cory. I'll let this question sit for a while, because that would also mean I'd have to load into home#index all the variables. But yeah, thanks for reinforcing my second option!